# Linq to SQL: Select categories that have no subcategories

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql

I need to grab all categories that don't have subcategories

```
1
^--1.1
^--1.2
    ^--1.2.3

2
^--2.1

3
```

In this example I would want to get [1.1], [1.2.3], [2.1] and [3].

My Categories table looks like this:

```
CategoryID | CategoryName | ParentID
```

I figure I should be selecting all the categories where it's CategoryID isn't used in any other category's ParentID field but I'm at a loss as to how to write that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
from c in model.Categories
where !(from inner_c in model.Categories
        select inner_c.ParentID).Contains(c.CategoryID)
select c
```

The subquery is key - we're trying to translate into LINQ:

```
SELECT * FROM categories WHERE categoryID NOT IN (SELECT parentID FROM categories)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
List<Category> GetChildlessCategories()
{
    List<int> parentIds = context.Categories.Select(x => x.ParentId);
    return context.Categories.Where(c => !parentsIds.Contains(c.CategoryId));
}
```

It is easier to work on the flat table that to load it to a relational structure and try to process each node again the whole (flat) structure again.